# Flask is not logging HTTP Requests

Tags: python, flask

There is a client machine which sends HTTP requests to my IP address.

I can read these requests if I listen on port 5000 using netcat as shown below:

```
nc -lvp 5000
```

The request looks like shown below when logged by netcat:

```
GET /test/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: <my_ip>:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.13.6
```

Now, I ran Flask server on port 5000 as well to capture the above HTTP requests using the code below:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def log_request_info():
    app.logger.debug('Headers: %s', request.headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Questions:

1. Why does Flask not log the HTTP GET requests coming to my machine on port 5000 even though nc does?
2. If Flask is already running on port 5000 then how am I able to run nc on the same port to listen for connections?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe flask is just listening on `127.0.0.1:5000` instead of what you want `0.0.0.0:5000`. You should run it as `app.run(host="0.0.0.0")`. And btw you can test it by opening `localhost:5000` in your browser.

Comment: Thanks, it works when I listen using IP address: 0.0.0.0

Comment: So, issue resolved?

Comment: Yes, the issue is resolved.